# flutter doctor --verbose reporting 0 issues from command line but 1 issue when launched from pubspec.yaml Flutter commands

Tags: android, linux, flutter

When I run flutter doctor --verbose from command line I get 0 issues as seen here :

[flutter doctor success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scOW3.png),

[flutter doctor success --verbose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtMsa.png)

When I open my pubspec.yaml file in android studio and click the flutter doctor command from the Flutter commands line that appears I get 1 issue with android tool chain. Specifically the Android SDK location. I'm not sure how to proceed. I would love to work within AndriodStudio and use the built-in logging functionality. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is image of the Flutter doctor failing : [flutter doctor failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTJkr.png). Here is an image of the Flutter commands available when pubspec.yaml is open : [flutter commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEnxY.png)

I imagine fixing this will also fix the devices not found issue I'm experiencing as well. Again, from the command line all of my devices are found and I can launch my flutter application on my phone and virtual device but in andriod studio there are no devices found by flutter... Ty ty friends.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Try to [edit] your question and copy-paste the output to the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to set sdk location again **after** restarting. This also fixed the devices not found issue.